# devise registration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I just set up devise and receive the following error after I sign up or sign in.

```
undefined local variable or method `root_path' for
#<Devise::SessionsController:0x007fc514ea6920>
```

I do have the following in my routes.rb file

```
root :to => "store#index", :as => "store"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop webrick, remove the `, :as => "store"` from the `root` route, restart webrick.

Comment: Likely because, by adding `:as => "store"`, the `root_path` was "redefined" to `store_path`. Add the `:as => "store"` and do a `rake routes` at the command line and look for the root path in the result. Then remove `:as` and see the rake route results again.